# Is/are or Does which do i need to use

Tags: grammar

I always suffering when i make a question. I can not decide when do i need to use is/are or does. Today's problem: is something available or does something available?
Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: Is "available" an adjective or a verb?

Comment: Do we say (1) "Something availables" OR (2) "Something is available"? Do we ask (1) "Do I need something?" OR (2) "Am I need something?"

Comment: (1) *Is something available?* (2) *Are some things available?* (3) *Does something make it available?* All of those are grammatical. Your question is too broad to answer in any meaningful way other than just *yes* or *it depends*. Also note that *available* is an adjective, not a verb. It, itself, has nothing to do with the use of *is*, *are*, or *does*.

Comment: rewrite just for you: [I always suffer when I ask question. I cannot decide when I need to use is/are or does. Today's problem: is something available or does something available? Thanks for the answers in advance.] You need to review: the present simple and how to ask a question with the verb to be.

Answer (score 0):

Some things are available. Other things are not available. I cannot easily think of a sentence where the verb 'to do' would be used with 'available'.

Comment: Does he make it available?

Comment: True. In this case 'available' is an adjective referring to 'it'. The verb choice comes from the rest of the sentence. He is hungry. Does she get hungry? The adjective doesn't seem to make any difference.